# Convert PHP Joomla to the HTML

Tags: php, joomla

I've downloaded a PHP Joomla template, and I want to remove all PHP/Joomla statements from the code (I want to convert that code to the static HTML code)

I don't know what to do with the e.g.

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="user" />
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" />
```

here is the code from the Index.php page: [LINK](http://pastebin.com/jpNVrGyM)

Comment: Basically, you just want to retrieve the layout?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the layout, why don't you just right click on the page, and select View Source?

Comment: Or save the page and tweak the file as needed.

Answer (score 1):

http://pastebin.com/hW87Xtki

This is what you will get, if you remove the jdocs. Its a complete blank page now. Jdoc is like a place holder for joomla components. If you dont want to put any joomla components then jdocs are useless. you can freely delete them wherever you want(provided you are not going to use this with joomla).